# Foreign key attribute in Django model NOT getting de-serialized

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I am trying to serialize a foreign key element of a model but when I am de-serializing the object I am not getting the foreign key entry in the `validated_data` list.

The **models.py** for the **Employer** application is as follows:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib import admin


class Employer(models.Model):

entity = models.ForeignKey('entities.Entity',
related_name='employers_ent', null=True,blank=True)
profile = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
ROLE = (
    ('1', 'Admin'),
    ('2', 'Manager'),)
employer_role = models.CharField(max_length=2,  choices=ROLE, default='1')
name = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null=True,blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length= 500, null=True,blank=True)
contact_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

The views.py from which I am calling the EmployerSerializer is ->

```
@login_required
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def employers_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        employers = Employer.objects.all()
        employer_serializer = EmployerSerializer(employers, many=True)
        return Response(employer_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print "I am here yay"
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        data['username']=request.user.username
        try:
            e = Entity.objects.get(company_name=data['entity'])
            e.save()
            data['entity']= e
        except Exception as e:
            e , created = Entity.objects.update_or_create(company_name=data['entity'])
            e.save()
            data['entity']=e
        employer_serializer = EmployerSerializer(data=data)
        print employer_serializer
        print employer_serializer.is_valid()
        if employer_serializer.is_valid():
            employer_serializer.save()
            return Response(employer_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(employer_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The serializers.py for the employer app looks like :

```
from app.employers.models import Employer
from rest_framework import serializers
from app.accounts.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from app.entities.serializers import EntitySerializer
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class EmployerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    print "here I am "

    id = serializers.IntegerField(source='pk', read_only = True)
    username = serializers.CharField(source='profile.username')
    entity = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='entity.company_name')
    # employer_role = serializers.CharField(default='1')

    class Meta:
        print("This is me")
        model = Employer
        entity = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'employer_role', 'name', 'contact_number','entity', 'email')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        print("I have come into the world")
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
        instance.contact_number = validated_data.get('contact_number', instance.contact_number)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.employer_role = validated_data.get('employer_role', instance.employer_role)

        instance.save()
        print instance

        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print ("wild and free")
        user_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        username = user_data['username']
        log.info(validated_data)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)

        if user is not None:
            profile = Employer.objects.create(profile=user, **validated_data)

            return profile
```

I am getting a response like :
`{"id":24,"username":"subhajitm6@gmail.com","employer_role":"1","name":"Uhyres","contact_number":1111,"entity":null,"email":"admin@textnook.in"}`

How can I resolve this issue and get a proper response for the `entity` field. Can someone please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Why its _models.ForeignKey('entities.Entity'..._ and not only the model name Entity in the Employer model ? Try to use the model name instead.

Comment: No , I tried it. That did not work. is there anyway I can send some attribute to the serializer class and access it from the create function?

Comment: Can you try replacing entity as **StringRelatedField** with employers_ent as **PrimaryKeyRelatedField** and don't define it in the Meta.

Comment: And about your query in the comment for extra content you can pass context to the serializer class ex.  EmployerSerializer(employer, context={'entity': entity}) and access through self.context. You can also use [extra_kwargs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments).